# Альтернатива keyPress() и keyRelease()

Tags: java, ооп

Работаю над созданием автокликера и вот столкнулся с проблемой: `keyPress()` и `keyRelease()` отказываются эмулировать нажатия клавиш в игре. Под виндовыми окнами все работает прекрасно, но в игре все туго.

Возможно, есть альтернативы написания такого кода:

Код Java(TM) 2 Platform Standard Edition 5.0

```
try {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(15);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: А подробнее об игре если можно - java2d/windowed/full screen/exclusive/lwjgl/jogl/libgdx/ - разные подходы будут использоваться.

Comment: Игра Growtopia - windowed  больше инфы не знаю